# Multiple-entry Chinese visa

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, china, uk-citizens

I'm a British Citizen with a British passport.  I applied for a 2 year Chinese tourism multi-entry visa, which I received and will end in March 2019.

I've booked some flights to go back to China for Chinese new year in February 2019, however considering how much information I had to provide the visa application centre originally to get the visa, I'm wary that just rocking up at the airport is that straightforward.

The type of things I had to provide originally were letters from my employer proving I had a job, flight bookings, hotel bookings  and probably other things I'm forgetting.  Will China allow me entry without seemingly having to provide this all again, or Do i indeed have to resubmit things like letters of employment (in the UK.  Again just visiting China for tourism)?

Comment: The general practice when entering a country on a visa is to have the documents similar to what was provided when applying for the visa. Of course it is rarely checked, but that is the general rule.

Answer (score 1):

The general practice when entering a country on a visa is to have the documents similar to what was provided when applying for the visa. Of course it is rarely checked, but that is the general rule.

> Will China allow me entry without seemingly having to provide this all
>   again, or Do i indeed have to resubmit things like letters of
>   employment

Nobody can determine that. Depends on the immigration officer.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of providing a contrary view, I've had many multiple entry visas for China over the last 8 years and enter China regularly either by land from Hong Kong or Macau or by air. The number of entries to China must be in the hundreds. I have yet to be asked to provide any supporting documentation that was provided in the visa application.

I'm also a "British" citizen with UK passport. I've had visa categories F, L and M.

That being said, your mileage may vary and since it's a long flight from the UK to China just to be denied entry, it's probably best to bring the documentation.